# css max-device-width 800 not matching for android phone

Tags: android, css, media, viewport, nexus-s

I'm making a site that should look different on mobiles, than how it looks on desktops. I'm testing it on a nexus-s - android 2.3 if that is relevant. I've set the `viewport` meta tag to `device-width`.

In the CSS I've added a `@media all and (max-device-width: 800px)` rule that has all the mobile specific styles. But none of that is being applied. I've made all of it `!important` and put it in as the last block in the css file, but still it's not working.

Anyone experiences something like this?

Comment: This rule should work, but it's hard to help you without more infos. Could you paste some relevant parts of your css files so we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [mobile screen width](http://musaul.net/lab/mobile/cssres/) test page for checking various screen resolutions on mobile devices. On my HTC Desire the width rule matches 800px, if I specify an `initial-scale` of 0.67 in the viewport meta.

If I set the `width` to `device-width` with an `initial-scale` of `1.0`, the screen comes up as 533 pixels in the CSS rule.

Check it out on your phone, and see if it helps with your page.

Comment: Cool. The page was really useful for checking out the different settings. But it is annoying that you have to set this initial-scale. Also why does it set the width to 1440 on the first link?

Comment: Mobile phones have a high dpi, so they scale it to make the viewport bigger, which the user can pan around.

The width was 1440 because thats how wide the widest element is on the page. There is also a probable bug in the android browser which causes the display-width to come across as wide as the widest element. There's a commented out `border-bottom` rule in the page which demonstrates that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put this in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment rather than an answer.